# ERROR 000735: Expression: Value is required with ERROR 000728: Field does not exist within table

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, arcfm, error-000735, error-000728

I have a script written (exported from model builder 10.8), and syntax revised, to essentially to export ArcFM data to take a specific field, and bring it into another field that is not ArcFM in memory. This script catches any cases where the ArcFM field does not match the non ArcFM field, and return the ArcFM field. I have written the script below (albeit with quite a few intermediary steps for the script to repeat the process daily effectively), but I am getting hung up with this error:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:\ESRI\Python Scripts\OMS Tie Device UpdateTST.py", line 90, in <module>
    pass")""")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.8\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 3647, in CalculateField
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000728: Field "TIESWITCHINDICATOR", "myCalc( !Tie!, !TIESWITCHINDICATOR!)", "PYTHON_9.3", "def myCalc (tie, tieswitch):
    if(tie == -1 and tieswitch is None):
        return -1
    elif(tie == 0 and tieswitch is None):
        return 0
    elif(tie == -1 and tieswitch == 'N'):
        return -1
    elif(tie == 0 and tieswitch == 'Y'):
        return 0
    else:
        pass") does not exist within table
ERROR 000735: Expression: Value is required
Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

I am truly not sure why this is the case, as we have added all the scenarios in our data for the value to exist....and regardless, the pass should carry on running the script. We have also confirmed that the field names are correct.

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# OMS Tie Device UpdateTST.py
# Created on: 2023-05-10 08:28:32.00000
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Description: 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Set the necessary product code
#import arceditor

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

print "Arcpy imported"

# Load required toolboxes
arcpy.ImportToolbox("S:/ESRI/Models/ExportByFeeder.tbx")

print "Export by Feeder toolbox imported"

# Local variables:
ARCFMADM_ElecGeomNetwork__2_ = "Database Connections\\arcfmdbtst as arcfmadm.sde\\ARCFMADM.ElectricDataset\\ARCFMADM.ElecGeomNetwork"
ExportByFeeder_gdb = "S:\\ESRI\\ESRI Data\\File Geodatabases\\OMSTieDeviceUpdate\\ExportByFeeder.gdb"
New_File_Geodatabase_gdb_2 = ExportByFeeder_gdb
OMSTieDeviceUpdate__2_ = "S:\\ESRI\\ESRI Data\\File Geodatabases\\OMSTieDeviceUpdate"
StagingLayers_gdb = OMSTieDeviceUpdate__2_
OMSTieDeviceUpdate = "S:\\ESRI\\ESRI Data\\File Geodatabases\\OMSTieDeviceUpdate"
New_File_Geodatabase_gdb_1 = OMSTieDeviceUpdate
ARCFMADM_DynamicProtectiveDevice = "Database Connections\\arcfmdbtst as arcfmadm.sde\\ARCFMADM.ElectricDataset\\ARCFMADM.DynamicProtectiveDevice"
DynamicProtectiveDevice_From_Export_Feeder_Tool = "S:\\ESRI\\ESRI Data\\File Geodatabases\\OMSTieDeviceUpdate\\ExportByFeeder.gdb\\DynamicProtectiveDevice"
ARCFMADM_Switch = "Database Connections\\arcfmdbtst as arcfmadm.sde\\ARCFMADM.ElectricDataset\\ARCFMADM.Switch"
Switch_From_Export_Feeder_Tool = "S:\\ESRI\\ESRI Data\\File Geodatabases\\OMSTieDeviceUpdate\\ExportByFeeder.gdb\\Switch"
Export_Feeder_Switches_with_Incorrect_Tie_Switch_Indicator_Status_ = "S:\\ESRI\\ESRI Data\\File Geodatabases\\OMSTieDeviceUpdate\\StagingLayers.gdb\\Switch_Staging"
Export_by_Feeder_Switches_TieSwitch_Indicator_Corrected_ = Export_Feeder_Switches_with_Incorrect_Tie_Switch_Indicator_Status_
Switches_Staging_ = Export_by_Feeder_Switches_TieSwitch_Indicator_Corrected_
Switches_Staging_Layer_ = "Switch_Staging_Layer"
ARCFM_Production___Export_by_Feeder_Join__2_ = Switches_Staging_Layer_
ARCFM_Switch_Layer = "Switch_Layer"
Switch_Layer = ARCFM_Production___Export_by_Feeder_Join__2_
ARCFM_Switch_Tie_Switch_Indicator_Corrected = Switch_Layer
Export_Feeder_DPDs_with_Incorrect_Tie_Switch_Indicator_Status = "S:\\ESRI\\ESRI Data\\File Geodatabases\\OMSTieDeviceUpdate\\StagingLayers.gdb\\DPD_Staging"
Export_by_Feeder_DPDs_TieSwitch_Indicator_Corrected = Export_Feeder_DPDs_with_Incorrect_Tie_Switch_Indicator_Status
DPD_Staging = Export_by_Feeder_DPDs_TieSwitch_Indicator_Corrected
DPD_Staging_Layer = "DPD_Staging_Layer"
ARCFM_Production___Export_by_Feeder_Join = DPD_Staging_Layer
ARCFM_DPD_Layer = "ARCFMDPDLayer"
ARCFMDPDLayer = ARCFM_Production___Export_by_Feeder_Join
ARCFM_DPD_Tie_Switch_Indicator_Corrected = ARCFMDPDLayer
ExportByFeeder_gdb__2_ = "S:\\ESRI\\ESRI Data\\File Geodatabases\\OMSTieDeviceUpdate\\ExportByFeeder.gdb"
StagingLayers_gdb__4_ = "S:\\ESRI\\ESRI Data\\File Geodatabases\\OMSTieDeviceUpdate\\StagingLayers.gdb"
Delete_succeeded__3_ = "true"
Delete_succeeded = Delete_succeeded__3_

# Process: Create File GDB
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(OMSTieDeviceUpdate, "ExportByFeeder", "CURRENT")

print "Export by Feeder File GDB Created"

# Process: Create File GDB (2)
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(OMSTieDeviceUpdate__2_, "StagingLayers", "CURRENT")

print "Staging File GDB Created"

print "Export by Feeder started..."

# Process: Export By Feeder
arcpy.gp.toolbox = "S:/ESRI/Models/ExportByFeeder.tbx";
# Warning: the toolbox S:/ESRI/Models/ExportByFeeder.tbx DOES NOT have an alias. 
# Please assign this toolbox an alias to avoid tool name collisions
# And replace arcpy.gp.ArcFMExportByFeeder(...) with arcpy.ArcFMExportByFeeder_ALIAS(...)
arcpy.gp.ArcFMExportByFeeder(ARCFMADM_ElecGeomNetwork__2_, "2M1;2M2;2M3;2M4;4M1;4M2;5M1;5M2;15M5;15M6;15M7;15M8;15M10;15M11;23M1;23M2;23M6;23M21;24M1;24M2;24M3;24M4;24M5;24M6;25M5;25M6;25M7;25M8;25M9;25M10;25M11;25M12;25M13;25M14;31M1;31M2;31M3;31M4;55M1;55M2;55M3;55M4;55M5;55M6;55M21;55M22;55M23;55M24;55M25;55M26;56M1;56M2;56M3;56M4;56M5;56M6;56M7;56M8", ExportByFeeder_gdb, "", "false", "false")

# Process: Select (2)
arcpy.Select_analysis(Switch_From_Export_Feeder_Tool, Export_Feeder_Switches_with_Incorrect_Tie_Switch_Indicator_Status_, "(Tie = -1 AND TIESWITCHINDICATOR IS NULL) OR (Tie = 0 AND TIESWITCHINDICATOR IS NULL) OR (Tie = -1 AND TIESWITCHINDICATOR = 'N') OR (Tie = 0 AND TIESWITCHINDICATOR = 'Y')")

print "Switch Select Complete"

# Process: Calculate Field (4)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Export_Feeder_Switches_with_Incorrect_Tie_Switch_Indicator_Status_, """"TIESWITCHINDICATOR", "myCalc( !Tie!, !TIESWITCHINDICATOR!)", "PYTHON_9.3", "def myCalc (tie, tieswitch):
    if(tie == -1 and tieswitch is None):
        return -1
    elif(tie == 0 and tieswitch is None):
        return 0
    elif(tie == -1 and tieswitch == 'N'):
        return -1
    elif(tie == 0 and tieswitch == 'Y'):
        return 0
    else:
        pass")""")

print "Switch FC 1 Complete"
                                
# Process: Calculate Field (5)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Export_by_Feeder_Switches_TieSwitch_Indicator_Corrected_, """"TIESWITCHINDICATOR", "reclass (!Tie!, !TIESWITCHINDICATOR!)", "PYTHON_9.3", "def reclass (tie, tieswitch):
    if(tie == -1):
        return 'Y'
    elif(tie == 0):
        return 'N'
    else:
       pass")""")

print "Switch FC 2 Complete"                                

# Process: Make Feature Layer (3)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Switches_Staging_, Switches_Staging_Layer_, "", "", "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;SHAPE SHAPE VISIBLE NONE;FM2_ObjectID FM2_ObjectID VISIBLE NONE;ANCILLARYROLE ANCILLARYROLE VISIBLE NONE;ENABLED ENABLED VISIBLE NONE;CREATIONUSER CREATIONUSER VISIBLE NONE;DATECREATED DATECREATED VISIBLE NONE;LASTUSER LASTUSER VISIBLE NONE;DATEMODIFIED DATEMODIFIED VISIBLE NONE;SUBTYPECD SUBTYPECD VISIBLE NONE;FACILITYID FACILITYID VISIBLE NONE;FEEDERID FEEDERID VISIBLE NONE;FEEDERID2 FEEDERID2 VISIBLE NONE;OPERATINGVOLTAGE OPERATINGVOLTAGE VISIBLE NONE;CONSTRUCTIONSTATUS CONSTRUCTIONSTATUS VISIBLE NONE;WORKORDERID WORKORDERID VISIBLE NONE;INSTALLATIONDATE INSTALLATIONDATE VISIBLE NONE;COMMENTS COMMENTS VISIBLE NONE;ELECTRICTRACEWEIGHT ELECTRICTRACEWEIGHT VISIBLE NONE;FEEDERINFO FEEDERINFO VISIBLE NONE;SYMBOLROTATION SYMBOLROTATION VISIBLE NONE;HYPERLINK HYPERLINK VISIBLE NONE;VOLTAGERATING VOLTAGERATING VISIBLE NONE;PHASEDESIGNATION PHASEDESIGNATION VISIBLE NONE;REMOTEOPERATED REMOTEOPERATED VISIBLE NONE;MAXCONTINUOUSCURRENT MAXCONTINUOUSCURRENT VISIBLE NONE;MAXOPERATINGVOLTAGE MAXOPERATINGVOLTAGE VISIBLE NONE;NORMALPOSITION_R NORMALPOSITION_R VISIBLE NONE;NORMALPOSITION_W NORMALPOSITION_W VISIBLE NONE;NORMALPOSITION_B NORMALPOSITION_B VISIBLE NONE;PRESENTPOSITION_R PRESENTPOSITION_R VISIBLE NONE;PRESENTPOSITION_W PRESENTPOSITION_W VISIBLE NONE;PRESENTPOSITION_B PRESENTPOSITION_B VISIBLE NONE;TIESWITCHINDICATOR TIESWITCHINDICATOR VISIBLE NONE;SCADACONTROLID SCADACONTROLID VISIBLE NONE;SCADAMONITORID SCADAMONITORID VISIBLE NONE;PREFERREDCIRCUITSOURCE PREFERREDCIRCUITSOURCE VISIBLE NONE;LABELTEXT LABELTEXT VISIBLE NONE;POLEOBJECTID POLEOBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;GANGOPERATED GANGOPERATED VISIBLE NONE;HFRAMEOBJECTID HFRAMEOBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;SWITCHINGFACILITYOBJECTID SWITCHINGFACILITYOBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;UNDERGROUNDSTRUCTUREOBJECTID UNDERGROUNDSTRUCTUREOBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;OWNER OWNER VISIBLE NONE;EQUIPMENT_DESCR EQUIPMENT_DESCR VISIBLE NONE;LOCATION_DESCR LOCATION_DESCR VISIBLE NONE;TEMPSWITCHTYPE TEMPSWITCHTYPE VISIBLE NONE;HISTORICTABLENAME HISTORICTABLENAME VISIBLE NONE;HISTORICOID HISTORICOID VISIBLE NONE;HISTORICFEEDER HISTORICFEEDER VISIBLE NONE;SUSPECTDATA SUSPECTDATA VISIBLE NONE;SAP_LOC SAP_LOC VISIBLE NONE;SAP_EQ SAP_EQ VISIBLE NONE;NOMENCLATURE NOMENCLATURE VISIBLE NONE;BAY_NUMBER BAY_NUMBER VISIBLE NONE;HEALTH HEALTH VISIBLE NONE;RISKSCORE RISKSCORE VISIBLE NONE;POINT_X POINT_X VISIBLE NONE;POINT_Y POINT_Y VISIBLE NONE;MAINTENANCE_PLAN MAINTENANCE_PLAN VISIBLE NONE;SOL_RULEID SOL_RULEID VISIBLE NONE;SOL_OVERRIDE SOL_OVERRIDE VISIBLE NONE;SOR_RULEID SOR_RULEID VISIBLE NONE;SOR_OVERRIDE SOR_OVERRIDE VISIBLE NONE;SL_RULEID SL_RULEID VISIBLE NONE;SL_OVERRIDE SL_OVERRIDE VISIBLE NONE;SR_RULEID SR_RULEID VISIBLE NONE;SR_OVERRIDE SR_OVERRIDE VISIBLE NONE;SR2_RULEID SR2_RULEID VISIBLE NONE;SR2_OVERRIDE SR2_OVERRIDE VISIBLE NONE;SR_MS_RULEID SR_MS_RULEID VISIBLE NONE;SR_MS_OVERRIDE SR_MS_OVERRIDE VISIBLE NONE;PRI_SOURCE PRI_SOURCE VISIBLE NONE;SEC_SOURCE SEC_SOURCE VISIBLE NONE;FM2_FeederID FM2_FeederID VISIBLE NONE;EnergizedPhases EnergizedPhases VISIBLE NONE;SourceCount SourceCount VISIBLE NONE;Loop Loop VISIBLE NONE;Tie Tie VISIBLE NONE")

print "Switch FL 1 Complete"
                                
# Process: Make Feature Layer (4)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(ARCFMADM_Switch, ARCFM_Switch_Layer, "", "", "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;ANCILLARYROLE ANCILLARYROLE VISIBLE NONE;ENABLED ENABLED VISIBLE NONE;CREATIONUSER CREATIONUSER VISIBLE NONE;DATECREATED DATECREATED VISIBLE NONE;LASTUSER LASTUSER VISIBLE NONE;DATEMODIFIED DATEMODIFIED VISIBLE NONE;SUBTYPECD SUBTYPECD VISIBLE NONE;FACILITYID FACILITYID VISIBLE NONE;FEEDERID FEEDERID VISIBLE NONE;FEEDERID2 FEEDERID2 VISIBLE NONE;OPERATINGVOLTAGE OPERATINGVOLTAGE VISIBLE NONE;CONSTRUCTIONSTATUS CONSTRUCTIONSTATUS VISIBLE NONE;WORKORDERID WORKORDERID VISIBLE NONE;INSTALLATIONDATE INSTALLATIONDATE VISIBLE NONE;COMMENTS COMMENTS VISIBLE NONE;ELECTRICTRACEWEIGHT ELECTRICTRACEWEIGHT VISIBLE NONE;FEEDERINFO FEEDERINFO VISIBLE NONE;SYMBOLROTATION SYMBOLROTATION VISIBLE NONE;HYPERLINK HYPERLINK VISIBLE NONE;VOLTAGERATING VOLTAGERATING VISIBLE NONE;PHASEDESIGNATION PHASEDESIGNATION VISIBLE NONE;REMOTEOPERATED REMOTEOPERATED VISIBLE NONE;MAXCONTINUOUSCURRENT MAXCONTINUOUSCURRENT VISIBLE NONE;MAXOPERATINGVOLTAGE MAXOPERATINGVOLTAGE VISIBLE NONE;NORMALPOSITION_R NORMALPOSITION_R VISIBLE NONE;NORMALPOSITION_W NORMALPOSITION_W VISIBLE NONE;NORMALPOSITION_B NORMALPOSITION_B VISIBLE NONE;PRESENTPOSITION_R PRESENTPOSITION_R VISIBLE NONE;PRESENTPOSITION_W PRESENTPOSITION_W VISIBLE NONE;PRESENTPOSITION_B PRESENTPOSITION_B VISIBLE NONE;TIESWITCHINDICATOR TIESWITCHINDICATOR VISIBLE NONE;SCADACONTROLID SCADACONTROLID VISIBLE NONE;SCADAMONITORID SCADAMONITORID VISIBLE NONE;PREFERREDCIRCUITSOURCE PREFERREDCIRCUITSOURCE VISIBLE NONE;LABELTEXT LABELTEXT VISIBLE NONE;POLEOBJECTID POLEOBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;GANGOPERATED GANGOPERATED VISIBLE NONE;HFRAMEOBJECTID HFRAMEOBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;SWITCHINGFACILITYOBJECTID SWITCHINGFACILITYOBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;UNDERGROUNDSTRUCTUREOBJECTID UNDERGROUNDSTRUCTUREOBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;OWNER OWNER VISIBLE NONE;EQUIPMENT_DESCR EQUIPMENT_DESCR VISIBLE NONE;LOCATION_DESCR LOCATION_DESCR VISIBLE NONE;TEMPSWITCHTYPE TEMPSWITCHTYPE VISIBLE NONE;HISTORICTABLENAME HISTORICTABLENAME VISIBLE NONE;HISTORICOID HISTORICOID VISIBLE NONE;HISTORICFEEDER HISTORICFEEDER VISIBLE NONE;SUSPECTDATA SUSPECTDATA VISIBLE NONE;SAP_LOC SAP_LOC VISIBLE NONE;SAP_EQ SAP_EQ VISIBLE NONE;SHAPE SHAPE VISIBLE NONE;NOMENCLATURE NOMENCLATURE VISIBLE NONE;BAY_NUMBER BAY_NUMBER VISIBLE NONE;HEALTH HEALTH VISIBLE NONE;RISKSCORE RISKSCORE VISIBLE NONE;POINT_X POINT_X VISIBLE NONE;POINT_Y POINT_Y VISIBLE NONE;MAINTENANCE_PLAN MAINTENANCE_PLAN VISIBLE NONE;PRI_SOURCE PRI_SOURCE VISIBLE NONE;SEC_SOURCE SEC_SOURCE VISIBLE NONE")

print "Switch FL 2 Complete"
                                
# Process: Add Join (2)
arcpy.AddJoin_management(ARCFM_Switch_Layer, "OBJECTID", Switches_Staging_Layer_, "FM2_ObjectID", "KEEP_COMMON")

print "Switch Join Complete"
                                
# Process: Calculate Field (6)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(ARCFM_Production___Export_by_Feeder_Join__2_, "ARCFMADM.Switch.TIESWITCHINDICATOR", "[Switch_Staging.TIESWITCHINDICATOR]", "VB", "")

print "Switch FC 3 Complete"
                                
# Process: Remove Join (2)
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(Switch_Layer, "")

print "Switch Join Complete"
                                
# Process: Select
arcpy.Select_analysis(DynamicProtectiveDevice_From_Export_Feeder_Tool, Export_Feeder_DPDs_with_Incorrect_Tie_Switch_Indicator_Status, "SUBTYPECD = 3 AND ((Tie = -1 AND TIESWITCHINDICATOR IS NULL) OR (Tie = 0 AND TIESWITCHINDICATOR IS NULL) OR (Tie = -1 AND TIESWITCHINDICATOR = 'N') OR (Tie = 0 AND TIESWITCHINDICATOR = 'Y'))")

print "DPD Select Complete"
                                
# Process: Calculate Field
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Export_Feeder_DPDs_with_Incorrect_Tie_Switch_Indicator_Status, """"TIESWITCHINDICATOR", "myCalc( !Tie!, !TIESWITCHINDICATOR!)", "PYTHON_9.3", "def myCalc (tie, tieswitch):
    if(tie == -1 and tieswitch is None):
        return -1
    elif(tie == 0 and tieswitch is None):
        return 0
    elif(tie == -1 and tieswitch == 'N'):
        return -1
    elif(tie == 0 and tieswitch == 'Y'):
        return 0
    else:
        pass")""")

print "DPD FC 1 Complete"

# Process: Calculate Field (3)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Export_by_Feeder_DPDs_TieSwitch_Indicator_Corrected, """"TIESWITCHINDICATOR", "reclass (!Tie!, !TIESWITCHINDICATOR!)", "PYTHON_9.3", "def reclass (tie, tieswitch):
    if(tie == -1):
        return 'Y'
    elif(tie == 0):
        return 'N'
    else:
        return")""")

print "DPD FC 2 Complete"

# Process: Make Feature Layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(DPD_Staging, DPD_Staging_Layer, "", "", "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;SHAPE SHAPE VISIBLE NONE;FM2_ObjectID FM2_ObjectID VISIBLE NONE;ANCILLARYROLE ANCILLARYROLE VISIBLE NONE;ENABLED ENABLED VISIBLE NONE;CREATIONUSER CREATIONUSER VISIBLE NONE;DATECREATED DATECREATED VISIBLE NONE;LASTUSER LASTUSER VISIBLE NONE;DATEMODIFIED DATEMODIFIED VISIBLE NONE;SUBTYPECD SUBTYPECD VISIBLE NONE;FACILITYID FACILITYID VISIBLE NONE;FEEDERID FEEDERID VISIBLE NONE;FEEDERID2 FEEDERID2 VISIBLE NONE;OPERATINGVOLTAGE OPERATINGVOLTAGE VISIBLE NONE;CONSTRUCTIONSTATUS CONSTRUCTIONSTATUS VISIBLE NONE;WORKORDERID WORKORDERID VISIBLE NONE;INSTALLATIONDATE INSTALLATIONDATE VISIBLE NONE;COMMENTS COMMENTS VISIBLE NONE;ELECTRICTRACEWEIGHT ELECTRICTRACEWEIGHT VISIBLE NONE;FEEDERINFO FEEDERINFO VISIBLE NONE;SYMBOLROTATION SYMBOLROTATION VISIBLE NONE;HYPERLINK HYPERLINK VISIBLE NONE;VOLTAGERATING VOLTAGERATING VISIBLE NONE;MAXCONTINUOUSCURRENT MAXCONTINUOUSCURRENT VISIBLE NONE;MAXINTERRUPTINGCURRENT MAXINTERRUPTINGCURRENT VISIBLE NONE;MAXOPERATINGVOLTAGE MAXOPERATINGVOLTAGE VISIBLE NONE;NORMALPOSITION_R NORMALPOSITION_R VISIBLE NONE;NORMALPOSITION_W NORMALPOSITION_W VISIBLE NONE;NORMALPOSITION_B NORMALPOSITION_B VISIBLE NONE;PRESENTPOSITION_R PRESENTPOSITION_R VISIBLE NONE;PRESENTPOSITION_W PRESENTPOSITION_W VISIBLE NONE;PRESENTPOSITION_B PRESENTPOSITION_B VISIBLE NONE;LABELTEXT LABELTEXT VISIBLE NONE;PHASEDESIGNATION PHASEDESIGNATION VISIBLE NONE;BILRATING BILRATING VISIBLE NONE;BYPASSSWITCH BYPASSSWITCH VISIBLE NONE;CLOSINGRESISTOR CLOSINGRESISTOR VISIBLE NONE;GANGOPERATED GANGOPERATED VISIBLE NONE;GROUNDRESISTANCE GROUNDRESISTANCE VISIBLE NONE;INTERRUPTINGMECHANISM INTERRUPTINGMECHANISM VISIBLE NONE;INTERRUPTINGMEDIUM INTERRUPTINGMEDIUM VISIBLE NONE;MOUNTINGTYPE MOUNTINGTYPE VISIBLE NONE;SCADACONTROLID SCADACONTROLID VISIBLE NONE;SCADAMONITORID SCADAMONITORID VISIBLE NONE;SHUNTMECHANISM SHUNTMECHANISM VISIBLE NONE;TIESWITCHINDICATOR TIESWITCHINDICATOR VISIBLE NONE;TRIPCOUNT TRIPCOUNT VISIBLE NONE;MANUFACTURER MANUFACTURER VISIBLE NONE;MODEL MODEL VISIBLE NONE;SERIALNUMBER SERIALNUMBER VISIBLE NONE;POLEOBJECTID POLEOBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;HFRAMEOBJECTID HFRAMEOBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;ELECTRICSTATIONOBJECTID ELECTRICSTATIONOBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;SWITCHINGFACILITYOBJECTID SWITCHINGFACILITYOBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;SEC_SOURCE SEC_SOURCE VISIBLE NONE;PRI_SOURCE PRI_SOURCE VISIBLE NONE;OWNER OWNER VISIBLE NONE;HISTORICTABLENAME HISTORICTABLENAME VISIBLE NONE;HISTORICOID HISTORICOID VISIBLE NONE;HISTORICFEEDER HISTORICFEEDER VISIBLE NONE;SUSPECTDATA SUSPECTDATA VISIBLE NONE;SAP_LOC SAP_LOC VISIBLE NONE;SAP_LOC_DESCR SAP_LOC_DESCR VISIBLE NONE;SAP_EQ_DESCR SAP_EQ_DESCR VISIBLE NONE;NOMENCLATUR NOMENCLATUR VISIBLE NONE;HEALTH HEALTH VISIBLE NONE;RISKSCORE RISKSCORE VISIBLE NONE;POINT_X POINT_X VISIBLE NONE;POINT_Y POINT_Y VISIBLE NONE;DPDL_RULEID DPDL_RULEID VISIBLE NONE;DPDL_OVERRIDE DPDL_OVERRIDE VISIBLE NONE;DPDR_RULEID DPDR_RULEID VISIBLE NONE;DPDR_OVERRIDE DPDR_OVERRIDE VISIBLE NONE;FM2_FeederID FM2_FeederID VISIBLE NONE;EnergizedPhases EnergizedPhases VISIBLE NONE;SourceCount SourceCount VISIBLE NONE;Loop Loop VISIBLE NONE;Tie Tie VISIBLE NONE")

print "DPD FL 1 Complete"
                                
# Process: Make Feature Layer (2)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(ARCFMADM_DynamicProtectiveDevice, ARCFM_DPD_Layer, "", "", "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;ANCILLARYROLE ANCILLARYROLE VISIBLE NONE;ENABLED ENABLED VISIBLE NONE;CREATIONUSER CREATIONUSER VISIBLE NONE;DATECREATED DATECREATED VISIBLE NONE;LASTUSER LASTUSER VISIBLE NONE;DATEMODIFIED DATEMODIFIED VISIBLE NONE;SUBTYPECD SUBTYPECD VISIBLE NONE;FACILITYID FACILITYID VISIBLE NONE;FEEDERID FEEDERID VISIBLE NONE;FEEDERID2 FEEDERID2 VISIBLE NONE;OPERATINGVOLTAGE OPERATINGVOLTAGE VISIBLE NONE;CONSTRUCTIONSTATUS CONSTRUCTIONSTATUS VISIBLE NONE;WORKORDERID WORKORDERID VISIBLE NONE;INSTALLATIONDATE INSTALLATIONDATE VISIBLE NONE;COMMENTS COMMENTS VISIBLE NONE;ELECTRICTRACEWEIGHT ELECTRICTRACEWEIGHT VISIBLE NONE;FEEDERINFO FEEDERINFO VISIBLE NONE;SYMBOLROTATION SYMBOLROTATION VISIBLE NONE;HYPERLINK HYPERLINK VISIBLE NONE;VOLTAGERATING VOLTAGERATING VISIBLE NONE;MAXCONTINUOUSCURRENT MAXCONTINUOUSCURRENT VISIBLE NONE;MAXINTERRUPTINGCURRENT MAXINTERRUPTINGCURRENT VISIBLE NONE;MAXOPERATINGVOLTAGE MAXOPERATINGVOLTAGE VISIBLE NONE;NORMALPOSITION_R NORMALPOSITION_R VISIBLE NONE;NORMALPOSITION_W NORMALPOSITION_W VISIBLE NONE;NORMALPOSITION_B NORMALPOSITION_B VISIBLE NONE;PRESENTPOSITION_R PRESENTPOSITION_R VISIBLE NONE;PRESENTPOSITION_W PRESENTPOSITION_W VISIBLE NONE;PRESENTPOSITION_B PRESENTPOSITION_B VISIBLE NONE;LABELTEXT LABELTEXT VISIBLE NONE;PHASEDESIGNATION PHASEDESIGNATION VISIBLE NONE;BILRATING BILRATING VISIBLE NONE;BYPASSSWITCH BYPASSSWITCH VISIBLE NONE;CLOSINGRESISTOR CLOSINGRESISTOR VISIBLE NONE;GANGOPERATED GANGOPERATED VISIBLE NONE;GROUNDRESISTANCE GROUNDRESISTANCE VISIBLE NONE;INTERRUPTINGMECHANISM INTERRUPTINGMECHANISM VISIBLE NONE;INTERRUPTINGMEDIUM INTERRUPTINGMEDIUM VISIBLE NONE;MOUNTINGTYPE MOUNTINGTYPE VISIBLE NONE;SCADACONTROLID SCADACONTROLID VISIBLE NONE;SCADAMONITORID SCADAMONITORID VISIBLE NONE;SHUNTMECHANISM SHUNTMECHANISM VISIBLE NONE;TIESWITCHINDICATOR TIESWITCHINDICATOR VISIBLE NONE;TRIPCOUNT TRIPCOUNT VISIBLE NONE;MANUFACTURER MANUFACTURER VISIBLE NONE;MODEL MODEL VISIBLE NONE;SERIALNUMBER SERIALNUMBER VISIBLE NONE;POLEOBJECTID POLEOBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;HFRAMEOBJECTID HFRAMEOBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;ELECTRICSTATIONOBJECTID ELECTRICSTATIONOBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;SWITCHINGFACILITYOBJECTID SWITCHINGFACILITYOBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;SEC_SOURCE SEC_SOURCE VISIBLE NONE;PRI_SOURCE PRI_SOURCE VISIBLE NONE;OWNER OWNER VISIBLE NONE;HISTORICTABLENAME HISTORICTABLENAME VISIBLE NONE;HISTORICOID HISTORICOID VISIBLE NONE;HISTORICFEEDER HISTORICFEEDER VISIBLE NONE;SUSPECTDATA SUSPECTDATA VISIBLE NONE;SAP_LOC SAP_LOC VISIBLE NONE;SHAPE SHAPE VISIBLE NONE;SAP_LOC_DESCR SAP_LOC_DESCR VISIBLE NONE;SAP_EQ_DESCR SAP_EQ_DESCR VISIBLE NONE;NOMENCLATUR NOMENCLATUR VISIBLE NONE;HEALTH HEALTH VISIBLE NONE;RISKSCORE RISKSCORE VISIBLE NONE;POINT_X POINT_X VISIBLE NONE;POINT_Y POINT_Y VISIBLE NONE")

print "DPD FL 2 Complete"
                                
# Process: Add Join
arcpy.AddJoin_management(ARCFM_DPD_Layer, "OBJECTID", DPD_Staging_Layer, "FM2_ObjectID", "KEEP_COMMON")

print "DPD Join Complete"
                                
# Process: Calculate Field (2)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(ARCFM_Production___Export_by_Feeder_Join, "ARCFMADM.DynamicProtectiveDevice.TIESWITCHINDICATOR", "[DPD_Staging.TIESWITCHINDICATOR]", "VB", "")

print "DPD FC 3 Complete"
                                
# Process: Remove Join
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(ARCFMDPDLayer, "DPD_Staging")

print "DPD Remove Join Complete"
                                
# Process: Delete (3)
arcpy.Delete_management(StagingLayers_gdb__4_, "")

print "Staging GDB deleted"
                                
# Process: Delete
arcpy.Delete_management(ExportByFeeder_gdb__2_, "")

print "Export by Feeder GDB deleted"

print "Tie Device Update Complete!!"
```